# Infinite conductivity, goldstone bosons and generalized voltage

Tags: quantum-field-theory, superconductivity, symmetry-breaking, goldstone-mode

Weinberg [1] has put forth an elegant argument (summarized in [2, Section 3.3] and at the bottom of the question), which suggests that the broken symmetry phase of any $U(1)$ gauge theory will be accompanied by infinite conductivity. I have a question regarding a key step in which he identifies the *voltage* as the functional derivative of the Hamiltonian with respect to charge density; i.e. $V(x) := \frac{\delta H}{\delta \rho}$.

I’m trying to accumulate evidence for the plausibility for Weinberg’s use of the *definition* $V(x) := \frac{\delta H}{\delta \rho}$. More precisely, I’d like to show, given two points $x_1,x_2 \in \mathbb{R}^d$, that $V(x_1) - V(x_2)$ is the potential difference that an experimenter would measure.

It’s possible to motivate Weinberg’s definition based on highschool electrostatics. Recall that the energy for a system of static charges is $H = \frac{1}{2}\int\int \rho(x)\rho(x’)/|x-x’|$ in $d=3$ spatial dimensions. Functionally differentiating this expression once with respect to $\rho$ indeed gives the well-known expression for the potential $V(x) = \int \rho(x’)/|x-x’|$ so LHS = RHS. However, it’s non-obvious that this is the right definition with magnetic fields and after coupling to Goldstones.

In order to see the difficulty, consider a minimal Lagrangian density that describes the symmetry broken phase (the Stueckelberg Lagrangian):
\begin{align}
    \mathcal{L}
    & = -  \frac{1}{4} F_{\mu\nu} F^{\mu\nu} - \frac{1}{2}m^2 (A_\mu-\partial_\mu G) (A^\mu-\partial^\mu G)
\end{align}
In passing to the Hamiltonian formulation, we first need to compute the canonical momenta (now using $\Pi$ to denote the momentum conjugate to the Goldstone):
\begin{align}
    \pi^0 & = 0 \\
    \pi^i & = F^{i0} \\
    & = \dot{A}^i - \partial_i A_0 \\
    \Pi & = m^2(\dot{G} - A_0)
\end{align}
from which we readily obtain
\begin{align}
    H  
    & = \int \mathrm{d}^d x \left[\Pi \dot{G} + \pi^i \dot{A}_i - \mathcal{L} \right] \\
    & = \int \mathrm{d}^d x \left[ \frac{1}{2m^2}\Pi^2 + \frac{1}{2} \pi_i \pi^i +  \frac{1}{4} F_{ij} F^{ij} + \frac{1}{2}m^2(A_i-\partial_i G)^2 + (\Pi + \pi^i \partial_i) A_0 \right] \\
    & = \int \mathrm{d}^d x \left[ \frac{1}{2m^2}\Pi^2 + \frac{1}{2} \pi_i \pi^i +  \frac{1}{4} F_{ij} F^{ij} + \frac{1}{2}m^2(A_i-\partial_i G)^2 + (\Pi - \partial_i\pi^i ) A_0 \right] 
\end{align}
where I integrated by parts. In particular, it’s not clear how functional derivatives with respect to $\Pi$ are related to *voltage*.

Is it possible to come up with a more convincing argument?

**Weinberg’s infinite conductivity argument**: Since the effective Lagrangian depends on the Goldstone field $G$ only via the combination $A_\mu - \partial_\mu G$, it follows that $G$ is canonically conjugate to the charge density $\rho$. Thus, in the Hamiltonian formulation, it satisfies an equation of motion $\dot{G} \propto \frac{\delta H}{\delta \rho} = V(x)$. Thus for time-independent field configurations corresponding to steady current, the potential difference vanishes.

[1] https://academic.oup.com/ptps/article/doi/10.1143/PTPS.86.43/1885987

[2] https://arxiv.org/abs/1401.1504

Comment: Evidence?  How do you compute the energy of a charge distribution in a Voltage configuration?

Comment: @CosmasZachos isn’t that only the case in the electrostatic case (discussed in my question).

Comment: @CosmasZachos I’ve now updated the question significantly based on your suggestion.

Comment: It's not clear to me what this question is asking: What is the definition of "voltage" here? It seems to me that Weinberg is simply calling $\frac{\partial H}{\partial \rho}$ "voltage" in *analogy* to electrostatics. In order to be able to have "evidence" for this being equal to "voltage" $V(x)$, you would have to have some independent definition of "voltage".

Comment: @ACuriousMind the voltage is something we should be able to measure in an experiment, which I’d argue is an independent definition. If you like, the question can be phrased in terms of evidence that $V$ is the experimental voltage.

Comment: @ACuriousMind I’ve now updated and clarified the question based on your comments.